# Cannot extract <link> element using HtmlAgilityPack and XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, rss, html-agility-pack

I am using the Html Agility pack to select out textual data from within rss xml. For every other node type (title, pubdate, guid .etc) I can select out the inner-text using XPath conventions however when querying "//link" or indeed "item/link" empty strings are returned.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractAllLinks(string rssSource)
{
    //Create a new document.
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    //Populate the document with an rss file.
    document.LoadHtml(rssSource);
    //Select out all of the required nodes.
    var itemNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("item/link");
    //If zero nodes were found, return an empty list, otherwise return the content of those nodes.
    return itemNodes == null ? new List<string>() : itemNodes.Select(itemNode => itemNode.InnerText).ToList();
}
```

Does anybody have an understanding of why this element behaves differently to the others?

Additional: Running "item/link" returns zero nodes. Running "//link" returns the correct number of nodes however the inner text is zero chars in length.

Using the below test data, with "//name" returns a single record for "fred" however with "//link" a single record with an empty string is returned.

```
<site><link>Hello World</link><name>Fred</name></site>
```

I am certain its because of the world "link". If I change it to "linkz" it works perfectly.

The below workaround works perfectly. However I would like to understand why searching on "//link" does not work as other elements do.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractAllLinks(string rssSource)
{
    rssSource = rssSource.Replace("<link>", "<link-renamed>");
    rssSource = rssSource.Replace("</link>", "</link-renamed>");
    //Create a new document.
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    //Populate the document with an rss file.
    document.LoadHtml(rssSource);
    //Select out all of the required nodes.
    var itemNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link-renamed");
    //If zero nodes were found, return an empty list, otherwise return the content of those nodes.
    return itemNodes == null ? new List<string>() : itemNodes.Select(itemNode => itemNode.InnerText).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you print the `DocumentNode.OuterHtml`, you will see the problem :

```
var html = @"<site><link>Hello World</link><name>Fred</name></site>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```

**output :**

```
<site><link>Hello World<name>Fred</name></site>
```

`link` happen to be one of some *special tags*<sup>*</sup> that is treated as self-closing tag by HAP. You can alter this behavior by setting `ElementsFlags` before parsing the HTML, for example :

```
var html = @"<site><link>Hello World</link><name>Fred</name></site>";
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("link");  //remove link from list of special tags
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//link");
foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
{
    Console.WriteLine(link.InnerText);
}
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0FFjSS)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<site><link>Hello World</link><name>Fred</name></site>
Hello World
```

---

*) Complete list of the *special tags* besides `link`, that included in the `ElementsFlags` dictionary by default, can be seen in the source code of [`HtmlNode.cs`](https://github.com/alexandernyquist/HtmlAgilityPack/blob/master/Source/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlNode.cs). Some of the most popular among them are `<meta>`, `<img>`, `<frame>`, `<input>`, `<form>`, `<option>`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it was something to do with the word being reserved or indeed "special" but google wasn't my friend today. Marked as accepted.